# How can I set the relevant property of an Orbeon element to depends on if a previous element is visited or not?

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I am trying to create in a form some elements that are visible if one specific element has been visited or not. Is it possible?

At this moment, I only can achieve this copying the relevant part of the first element to the others one, but, in the case on one element depends on many others elements, the relevant rule is too large. Then I am looking for some way to simply this: is there any kind of function like "isVisible()"?

Something like (i.e. control-2 must be visible only if control-1 is visible):

`<xf:bind id="control-2-bind" ref="control-2" name="control-2" relevant="isVisible($control-1)"/>`

**EDITED:**
An example of form, where control-5 must be shown only if control-4 is shown.

```
<xh:html xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
     xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
     xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
     xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
     xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
     xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
     xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:xxforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
     xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder">
<xh:head>
    <xh:title>Untitled Form</xh:title>
    <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">

        <!-- Main instance -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance">
            <form>
                <section-1>
                    <control-3/>
                    <control-4/>
                    <control-5/>

                </section-1>
            </form>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Bindings -->
        <xf:bind xmlns:dataModel="java:org.orbeon.oxf.fb.DataModel" id="fr-form-binds"
                 ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
            <xf:bind id="section-1-bind" name="section-1" ref="section-1">
                <xf:bind id="control-3-bind" ref="control-3" name="control-3"/>
                <xf:bind id="control-4-bind" ref="control-4" name="control-4"
                         relevant="$control-3='one'"/>
                <xf:bind id="control-5-bind" ref="control-5" name="control-5"
                         relevant="xxforms:visited($control-4)"/>

            </xf:bind>
        </xf:bind>

        <!-- Metadata -->
        <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-metadata">
            <metadata>
                <application-name>asd</application-name>
                <form-name>asd</form-name>
                <title xml:lang="en">Untitled Form</title>
                <description xml:lang="en"/>
            </metadata>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Attachments -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments">
            <attachments>
                <css mediatype="text/css" filename="" size=""/>
                <pdf mediatype="application/pdf" filename="" size=""/>
            </attachments>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- All form resources -->
        <!-- Don't make readonly by default in case a service modifies the resources -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-resources" xxf:readonly="false">
            <resources>
                <resource xml:lang="en">
                    <control-3>
                        <item>
                            <label>First choice</label>
                            <value>one</value>
                        </item>
                        <item>
                            <label>Second choice</label>
                            <value>two</value>
                        </item>
                        <item>
                            <label>Third choice</label>
                            <value>three</value>
                        </item>
                        <label/>
                        <hint/>
                    </control-3>
                    <control-4>
                        <label>Input</label>
                        <hint/>
                    </control-4>
                    <control-5>
                        <label>Visited</label>
                        <hint/>
                    </control-5>
                    <section-1>
                        <label>Untitled Section</label>
                    </section-1>

                </resource>
            </resources>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Utility instances for services -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-service-request-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <request/>
        </xf:instance>

        <xf:instance id="fr-service-response-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <response/>
        </xf:instance>

    </xf:model>
</xh:head>
<xh:body>
    <fr:view>
        <fr:body xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
                 xmlns:dataModel="java:org.orbeon.oxf.fb.DataModel"
                 xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
                 xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline">
            <fr:section id="section-1-control" bind="section-1-bind">
                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/section-1/label"/>
                <fr:grid>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:select1 id="control-3-control" appearance="full" bind="control-3-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-3/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-3/hint"/>

                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                <xf:itemset ref="$form-resources/control-3/item">
                                    <xf:label ref="label"/>
                                    <xf:value ref="value"/>
                                </xf:itemset>
                            </xf:select1>

                        </xh:td>

                    </xh:tr>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:input id="control-4-control" bind="control-4-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-4/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-4/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>


                            </xf:input>
                        </xh:td>
                    </xh:tr>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:output id="control-5-control" bind="control-5-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-5/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-5/hint"/>

                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                            </xf:output>
                        </xh:td>
                    </xh:tr>
                </fr:grid>
            </fr:section>
        </fr:body>
    </fr:view>
</xh:body>
```

The code is not working. The control-5 is never shown. What is wrong there?

**EDITED:** An example using the proposed solution "instance('visited')"

```
<xh:html xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
     xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
     xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
     xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
     xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
     xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
     xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:xxforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
     xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder">
<xh:head>
    <xh:title>Untitled Form</xh:title>
    <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">

    <!-- Main instance -->
    <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance">
            <form>
                <section-1>
                    <control-3/>
                    <control-4/>
                    <control-5/>
                </section-1>
            </form>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Bindings -->
    <xf:bind xmlns:dataModel="java:org.orbeon.oxf.fb.DataModel" id="fr-form-binds"
                 ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
            <xf:bind id="section-1-bind" name="section-1" ref="section-1">
                <xf:bind id="control-3-bind" ref="control-3" name="control-3"/>
                <xf:bind id="control-4-bind" ref="control-4" name="control-4"
                         relevant="$control-3='one'"/>
                <xf:bind id="control-5-bind" ref="control-5" name="control-5"
                         relevant="instance('visited') = 'true' and string-length($control-4)&gt;0"/>
            </xf:bind>
        </xf:bind>

        <!-- Keep track of visited status -->
    <xf:instance id="visited">
            <visited/>
        </xf:instance>
        <xf:setvalue ev:event="xxforms-visited" observer="control-4-control"
                     ref="instance('visited')"
                     value="'true'"/>
        <xf:setvalue ev:event="xxforms-unvisited" observer="control-4-control"
                     ref="instance('visited')"
                     value="'false'"/>

        <!-- Metadata -->
    <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-metadata">
            <metadata>
                <application-name>asd</application-name>
                <form-name>asd</form-name>
                <title xml:lang="en">Untitled Form</title>
                <description xml:lang="en"/>
            </metadata>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Attachments -->
    <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments">
            <attachments>
                <css mediatype="text/css" filename="" size=""/>
                <pdf mediatype="application/pdf" filename="" size=""/>
            </attachments>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- All form resources -->
    <!-- Don't make readonly by default in case a service modifies the resources -->
    <xf:instance id="fr-form-resources" xxf:readonly="false">
            <resources>
                <resource xml:lang="en">
                    <control-3>
                        <item>
                            <label>First choice</label>
                            <value>one</value>
                        </item>
                        <item>
                            <label>Second choice</label>
                            <value>two</value>
                        </item>
                        <item>
                            <label>Third choice</label>
                            <value>three</value>
                        </item>
                        <label/>
                        <hint/>
                    </control-3>
                    <control-4>
                        <label>Input</label>
                        <hint/>
                    </control-4>
                    <control-5>
                        <label>Visited</label>
                        <hint/>
                    </control-5>
                    <section-1>
                        <label>Untitled Section</label>
                    </section-1>

                </resource>
            </resources>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Utility instances for services -->
    <xf:instance id="fr-service-request-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <request/>
        </xf:instance>

        <xf:instance id="fr-service-response-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <response/>
        </xf:instance>
    </xf:model>
</xh:head>
<xh:body>
    <fr:view>
        <fr:body xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
                 xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
                 xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
                 xmlns:dataModel="java:org.orbeon.oxf.fb.DataModel">
            <fr:section id="section-1-control" bind="section-1-bind">
                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/section-1/label"/>
                <fr:grid>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:select1 id="control-3-control" appearance="full" bind="control-3-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-3/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-3/hint"/>

                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                <xf:itemset ref="$form-resources/control-3/item">
                                    <xf:label ref="label"/>
                                    <xf:value ref="value"/>
                                </xf:itemset>
                            </xf:select1>

                        </xh:td>

                    </xh:tr>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:input id="control-4-control" bind="control-4-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-4/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-4/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                            </xf:input>
                        </xh:td>
                    </xh:tr>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:output id="control-5-control" bind="control-5-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-5/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-5/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>                                
                            </xf:output>
                        </xh:td>
                    </xh:tr>
                </fr:grid>
            </fr:section>
        </fr:body>
    </fr:view>
</xh:body>
```

In this example, if you select 'First Choice' then, the Input Field is shown. And if you fill it with any value, 'Visited' label is therefore shown. This is the expected behaviour. But, if you later change the Radio Button to 'Second Choice', the Input Field is hidden but the 'Visited' label is still visible (only will be hidden if the user deletes the value of the input field, but now is hidden). This is undesired. There is any way to avoid this?

NOTE: I have added string-length() to be sure that is hidden if the value has been removed. Without it, always is visible.

Comment: Ok, string-length() is not really needed. The Form Builder is launching the events and modifying the value of the var `<xf:instance id="visited"><visited/></xf:instance>` setting a true by default. If we set the code directly into database, the form works without the string-length() code correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Orbeon Forms 4 there is:

- the [`xxf:visited()` function](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-xpath-functions#TOC-xxforms%3avisited)
- the `xxforms-visited` and `xxforms-unvisited` events

You have to be careful with dependencies when using the function, especially on `xf:bind`.

I tried to build a naive example, but it turns out that it doesn't work and I entered [an issue](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1470).

Here is a workaround, which requires adding a custom XForms instance:

```
<xf:bind id="control-5-bind" ref="control-5" name="control-5"
    relevant="instance('visited') = 'true'"/>

<xf:instance id="visited"><visited/></xf:instance>
<xf:setvalue event="xxforms-visited"   observer="control-4-control" ref="instance('visited')" value="'true'"/>
<xf:setvalue event="xxforms-unvisited" observer="control-4-control" ref="instance('visited')" value="'false'"/>
```

And here is the [complete example](https://gist.github.com/ebruchez/7920956).

Comment: I have edited my question to add an example of the use of the vistied() function, but is still not working. Probably I am using itincorrectly.

Comment: Also, I am not sure this is great UI. Wouldn't it be better to show the control if the other one contains a value, for example?

Comment: For complex flows in a form, where an element needs to be shown where other is also shown (and the last one is not mandatory) is not enough to look up for a value.  I can copy the relevant rule of the previous value but if the form is too long, we can obtain very long relevant rules (that decrease performance and increase complexity). I am going to test your proposal and I let you know.

Comment: I have tested your proposal, but the element `control-5` only is shown if I have clicked into the element `control-4` AND I perform any other event as changing the radio button value. It is close to the solution, but if the `control-4` field is not mandatory, we cannot assume that any user is going to click into the element (and also select other element). Therefore the solution is not going to work in all cases. But I appreciate your suggestion, is the closest idea I have tested. If you don't have any new suggestions I will wait until the issue is solved in version 4.5

Comment: Hi, @ebruchez any news about the issue? I see that has been removed from the milestone but it is still opened.

Comment: In case we edit the answer value, the visited value is still true and then, the next question will be always visible. Can we set as 'unvisited' to allow the user to correct his answers? In your example, if I change the radio button's answer to another value different to the first one, the Input field is hidden, but "Visited" is still showed.

Comment: @JorgeHortelano Sorry, there hasn't been more work on this issue. So you are still seeing the same problem? Did you try with Orbeon Forms 4.7?

Comment: No, I haven't tried yet. I will propose to my team to move to Orbeon 4.7 and I will let you know.

Comment: I have tried in version 4.7 and same issue. I have edited my question using the code of your example for a better clarification of the issue.

Comment: Now, if I combine part of your solution with the answer of here: [Remove the content of an element when is not relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046032/how-can-i-remove-the-content-of-an-element-when-is-not-relevant) finally I do not need any more to inherit all relevant rules! and my problem is solved. Thanks!